# map of fstream pointers in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, iostream

I want to have a map of (int, fstream*) and to modify it using some functions. I can easily modify it within main, but if I want to use it by sending the pointer to the fstream I got this compiler error  : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::fstream' to 'std::basic_fstream<_Elem,_Traits> *'

```
map<int, fstream*> m;
void func(fstream* f){
m[0] = *f; //compile error
}

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
fstream f("hi.txt");
func(&f); //error
m[0] = &f;   //work fine
f.close();
system("pause");
}
```

How can I change it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't dereference the pointer inside your function.

Use

```
void func(fstream* f){
  m[0] = f; //no more compile errors
}
```